# How can I mention whoever was mentioned in the command trigger?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to have my discord.py bot mention a member in a suspension from the server, then give them the suspended role. However, I don't know what to put in the embed and even if I just put something in there, it won't send the message. I also am not sure if it will role. Here's my code:

```
@bot.command(pass_ctx=True)
@commands.has_permission(administrator=True)
async def suspend(ctx, *, self, member = discord.Member):
 embed = discord.Embed(
 colour = discord.Colour.red(title='Successful Suspension'))
 [
   embed.add_field(name='Details', value='')]
 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 await member.add_roles('Suspended')
 else:
   await ctx.send('Insufficient Permissions.')
```

I also get a syntax error on the else: function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm going to answer your question. You can use `discord.Member.mention` *(In your case you can simply write `member.mention`)* to mention someone.

---

Secondly, I'm going to help with your embed:

- The arguments in the function are *messy*.
- Why did you put a title inside `discord.Colour.red()`? Thats a **colour**, and it's used for changing your embed sidebar color *(Also you can't change your text color if that's what you were trying to do).*
- In embed fields you cannot have nothing in the value. <strike>`value=''`</strike>
- You have a small typo, it's `has_permissions()`

*I don't like spoonfeeding,* but your code should look something like this:

```
    @bot.command(pass_ctx=True)
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def suspend(self, ctx, *, member = discord.Member):
           embed = discord.Embed(title='Succesful Suspension', colour=discord.Colour.red())
           embed.add_field(name='Details', value='A')
           await ctx.send(embed=embed)
           await member.add_roles('Suspended')
```

I alsoremoved the last part of your code because It didn't make sense. See [error handling.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)

---

I think this is all, hope that this worked and I recommend you to have a look [at the docs.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)
If someone finds anything wrong, tell me in the comments.